# Single particle density of states for non-free particle

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, bose-einstein-condensate, semiclassical, density-of-states

I am trying to find the single particle density of states in terms of the energy, for a system with the single particle 2D Hamiltonian:

$$H=\frac{p^2}{2 m}+\alpha x \text { with } 0<y<L, x>0$$

I.e. I'm looking for $g(\epsilon)$.

I have struggled quite a bit with this, since all resources I've found only derive the DOS for free particles with particle-in-a-box conditions.
Since x is not bounded like y, this is not possible here, and furthermore it is complicated by the linear potential $\alpha x$.
I didn't find solving the Schrödinger equation directly to be particularly fruitful, so I tried doing the normal gymnastics of trying to determine a volume in phase space which bounds the states of lower energy than a particular $\epsilon$.

What I have primarily tried then is to examine the implicit equation which can be obtained by considering a particular energy level $\epsilon$:

$$\begin{equation}
    1 = \frac{\hbar^2 k_{x}^2}{2m \epsilon} + \frac{n_{y}^2 \pi^2 \hbar^2}{2m \epsilon  L^2}+ \frac{\alpha}{\epsilon}x
\end{equation}$$

Where I figured that $k_{x}$ cannot be written in terms of a wave number. Now since the maximum value of x which satisfies the relation is $d= \frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}$, this equation seems to define the boundary of an elliptic paraboloid with volume $\frac{\pi}{2} d r_{1} r_{2} = \frac{4m \epsilon^2 L \pi^2}{\alpha h^2}$ (**note: h here is the real Plancks constant, not the reduced**).
Where $r_{1}= \sqrt{\frac{2m \epsilon}{\hbar^2}}$, $r_{2}=\sqrt{\frac{2 m \epsilon L^2}{\pi^2 \hbar^2}}$ and $d= \frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}$, so these parameters define the bounding ellipses and the height of the paraboloid.
This volume should then contain the energy states of energy less than $\epsilon$, i.e. $\Gamma(\epsilon) = \frac{4m \epsilon^2 L \pi^2}{\alpha h^2}$, which would make

$$ g(\epsilon) = \frac{8m \epsilon L \pi^2}{\alpha h^2}$$

The correct answer is stated as $$ g(\epsilon) = \frac{2m \epsilon L \pi}{\alpha h^2},$$ so I'm off by a factor of $4\pi$. The 4 is, however, easily removed once realizing that we must only consider positive values, so the contributions from all but the positive quadrant are removed ($x>0$ has already been incorporated).

I should note that the statement of this problem implies that there is a simpler/faster way to do this, since it is an old exam question. Specifically, there is a hint mentioning the semi-classical approximation. I have no idea how to use that hint however.